# How to make error type to be ParseErrorBundle String Void in happy?

Tags: haskell, parse-error, happy

I'm writing parser.y

```
%error { parseError }


parseError :: [Token] -> a
parseError _ = error "Parse error"
```

That is default in tutorials that I saw.
I want the error type to be `ParseErrorBundle String Void`.
What I should do for that?

Comment: Those are two different concepts of “error”. Megaparsec has “checked errors”, expressed as types; in particular, Megaparsec parameterizes its error type over the user’s error type, and if the user will throw no errors of their own, they can express that fact with Void. Happy, on the other hand, has “unchecked errors” that bypass the type system.